Embedded Rust on ESP32 using STD- std threading model vs async tasks with tokio
I want to know what approach is best for handling concurrency when considering development on embedded systems - which method has the most overhead, which will utilise more memory, and which method allows for better power saving. Similar questions have been asked before (e.g. async thread vs std thread); however, it is in the context of a standard system. I understand the effectiveness of each for managing CPU-bounded or IO-bounded tasks, but when it comes to managing both at once it becomes unclear to me simply because of the embedded context.
I get the impression that using tokio allows for finer control and will use less memory by default (as each std thread has its own stack). I'm also having trouble understanding in the context of threads being handled by the OS - I think with the ESP32 this would be passed to FreeRTOS under the hood but I'm not sure, and does FreeRTOS handling std threads have the same overhead that an OS like Linux or Windows would?
